# Bash Disappearing Array Elements

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am new to bash scripting and I do not understand why the following is happening. I have a script to read and store all lines of a txt file in an array. When I print out the array and add some text next to it the element seems to get overridden by the text instead of concatenated apart from the very last element.

Please see the image attached. It shows the output and the elements in the array. Each line of the txt file is an element in the array.

Thanks for any help.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' video.txt

declare -a array
while read -r line;
do
    array+=("$(echo "$line")")
done<video.txt

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$i and a little extra"
done
```

[image: output]

Comment: Why are you writing `$(echo "$line")` instead of just `"$line"`?

Comment: I think your file has CRLF newlines.

Comment: Use `dos2unix video.txt`

Comment: Yup. `$'\r'`s are not your friend.

Comment: BTW, `bash -x yourscript` -- logging each command the interpreter runs -- will make the issue a lot more obvious.

Comment: BTW, consider `readarray -t array <video.txt`, and then `echo "${i%$'\r'} and a little extra"`

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was to do with the CRLF newlines. I was importing a txt file from Windows to Debian without converting. To convert the file I used the command "tr -d '\15\32' < winfile.txt > unixfile.txt" as I couldn't get dos2unix working on my system.